# ssh double authentication by RSA keys

Tags: authentication, ssh

Let's imagine you have a client C and a server S.

the machine C connects to server S with ssh, using a RSA key to enable no passord connection. So C owns his private key, and have given to S the public key.

Giving that, can I use RSA keys to certifiate S ? I would like each time C tries to connect to S in ssh, it can be sure that he's really talking to S. So exactly like certificate X509, but with RSA keys ?

If i'm not wrong, it would be a double authentication ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to understand your question. can you please elaborate it more ?

Let me brief you summary of SSH connection.

Client connect to server

Client ask server identity. (This can be done by various Publickey algorithms)
For example: 
ssh-rsa, ssh-dsa etc are publickey format type
x509v3-ssh-rsa, x509v3-ssh-dsa etc are certificate format type

All above format is supported in Publickey algorithm.

FYI: Certificate is nothing but publickey with ownership information.

Now server sends its identify (publickey or certificate) to client

client validates it.

If it is okay then server ask client identify.

As per SSH protocol, it can be done via publickey, password, keyboard-interactive etc methods.

Now for no password method, publickey is right method. 
Here Publickey is method name. Internally supports many publickey and certificate method (which is same as mentioned above)

Client then choose publickey method and sends its identify either in form of publickey(ssh-rsa or ...) or certificate(x509v3-sshrsa or ...) to server.

Server would validate this identify.

If everything is okay then user is allowed to log in using SSH.

I hope it will clarify your doubt.

Comment: If I well understand, the first step you talk about, where client asks server identity, is done by the fingerprint received at first connection whose Nickolay talked about in its answer ?

Comment: As per your question you have mentioned. 
/////////////////////////
"Let's imagine you have a client C and a server S.

the machine C connects to server S with ssh, using a RSA key to enable no passord connection. So C owns his private key, and have given to S the public key. "
/////////////////////////
Above procedure is for user authentication

Comment: /////////////////////////
Giving that, can I use RSA keys to certifiate S ? I would like each time C tries to connect to S in ssh, it can be sure that he's really talking to S. So exactly like certificate X509, but with RSA keys ?

If i'm not wrong, it would be a double authentication ?

/////////////////////////
Above procedure is for server authentication

Comment: I couldn't understand this part too.
Giving that, can I use RSA keys to certifiate S ?

Comment: Yes, indeed i was lacking the fact the SSH server owns his own RSA keys (priv and pub). That's this public key that is used to get a fingerprint, which is presented to the client at first connection. So you were right, one key pair for user authentication (what I described in the first part of my question), and one key pair for server authentication. I was missing that last part

Comment: If you have got your answer then i would like to mark your question is resolved so people can read your post for future reference. Have a nice day !!!

Comment: yes sorry, i was searching the "mark resolved" button, not very familiar with the green mark :) hopefully some poeple already ask this on SO itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually each time server sends it's own public key to the client, and when you are first time connecting to the server you receive key's fingerprint and decides whether to trust him or not.

Comment: oh yes that is true ... so you can compare the key's fingerprint and the key itself to be sure ?

Comment: And anyway, would it be possible and useful to get a double authentication as I described ?